# How do i fix the sticky footer?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, footer

I have implemented a sticky footer on my wordpress website with this HTML code:

```
<style>
.footer{
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;}
</style>
```

But when viewing the post, the footer goes beyond a section on the website (attaching the image below) and screws up the carousal too. Ho do i fix this?
[footer going beyond the carousal section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVEJm.png)

I was trying to implement a sticky footer on my website. I was expecting it to get fixed at the bottom of the screen and not change anything else.

Comment: Check (position:sticky](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: Please add a minimal reproducible example - [ask]

Comment: Check this resource for help: https://mattkomarnicki.com/articles/css-sticky-footer

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply **z-index** property.

**z-index** property specifies the **stack order** of an element.

An element with greater stack order is always in **front of** an element with a lower stack order.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to give a `z-index` property to your `.footer` styles. An element with a larger z-index is always stacked on top of an element with a lower z-index. Elements with the same z-index are stacked in the order they appear in the document. By default, elements have a z-index of 0. However if your footer will always be visible, better go with `100` and sure it will come on top.

Also on the picture it looks like it doesn't take the 100% width. Maybe you have margin or padding set on the parent element. But also can try to use `100vw` which is gonna be the view width of the screen.

Comment: @DarkBee fair point there! :D edited

Comment: Thanks. Using z-index worked. But the other problem didn't solve. Adding that footer messes up the carousal structure. I am attaching the image of both before and after the sticky footer, you can clearly see the difference. How do i fix that problem? Before footer: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z4mkeMkylNAGw4FPWSws_jYEZywj9MJl/view?usp=sharing, After footer: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16JZpLAKaVECvzw4P5qVDktEvyqVBCZ55/view?usp=sharing